# how to get the nodes that that ended successfully during execution on argo

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows, argoproj

I used this line o get the failed pods: `workflow.failures` , so I would like to get the same info about the nodes that have finished successfully. Is there a command to get the information about the ones that ended correctly??. I'm using Argo 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `workflow.nodes` [global variable](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/docs/variables.md#exit-handler). But if you have kubectl access to get the JSON representation of the workflow, you can get information about executed nodes.

```sh
kubectl get wf my-workflow -ojson | jq '.status.nodes
```